# どうしてこの状況でjQueryセレクタは効果がない?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    function show_button2(){
        $('#demo').html('<button>Button 2</button>');
    }
</script>

<button onclick="show_button2();">Button 1</button>
<div id='demo'></div>
```

'Button 1'をクリックして, 下の'Button 2' (`id='demo'`の`<div>`の中に) が出てほしいんです.

でも, 上のコードだと, 'Button 1'をクリックしても, 何も出ないんです.

上記のコードによると, どうしてそのjQueryセレクタ (`$('#demo')`) は効果がないの?

この問題を解決する方法は何ですか?

Comment: そのコード走らせてみたらButton2がちゃんと出てきます。ブラウザコンソールにエラーメッセージがありますか。

Comment: こちらの環境(Safari 9.1.1)でも(示されていない部分を補うと)Button 2が普通に現れました。事象を再現できるようなHTML全体を質問文に追加してもらえませんか。

Comment: jQueryのロードはしてます？

Answer (score 1):

コメントでもBLUEPIXYさんが仰ってますがjQueryがロードされていない可能性があります。
下記は質問文のコードそのままですが動作しています。

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function show_button2(){
        $('#demo').html('<button>Button 2</button>');
    }
</script>

<button onclick="show_button2();">Button 1</button>
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: ここからエスパーの領域ですが下記の可能性もありますね。ただどちらにしろ情報が不足しているので追記してください。、、、「buttonの上に何かしらのElementが被っている」（記載しているコードが不足しているので情報を追加してください）、「ブラウザなど環境でclickが発動していない：この場合touchなどが効いている」（実行環境を記載してください）